# How to verify that a a user string input doesn't contain sql injection? in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, sql-injection

I tried to dig in the sanitize function but i didn't find the answer that I wanted, the question is how to check if a user input doesn't contain any sql injection? i'm using Nest JS (similar to node) if you have any idea of how I can do that it would help me a lot!

Comment: You should write code such that the user input can never be regarded as SQL, usually by using SQL parameters instead of concatenating user input into SQL commands. If you are already doing that, please add a specific example where it would be a problem.

Comment: NestJs comes with a very powerful orm `TypeOrm`, simply use the query builders from the same rather string concatenation of queries. Which should be enough to protect your application from sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking: You can't. Any input which might be SQL injection could, conceivably, also be genuine input (at least in certain narrow circumstances).

Don't try to detect SQL injection. Instead, use placeholders where possible and proper escaping where not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not on the NestJS side, it is on how you build the SQL query to execute.
You may use [`@nearform/sql`](https://github.com/nearform/sql) that:

> A simple SQL injection protection module that allows you to use ES6 template strings for escaped statements. Works with pg, mysql and mysql2 library.

It will protect you against malicious users input.
This module is battle-tested and [already in production](https://github.com/covidgreen/covid-green-backend-api/blob/current/package.json#L30) for Covid Government Tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared statements to avoid sql injection attacks
This [blog post](https://jtearl188.medium.com/preventing-sql-injection-on-node-js-cc8773fa265c) explains it quite well. for reference a snippet from the post.

```js
function authenticate(req, res, next){
    const username = req.query.username,
          password = req.query.password
    let preparedStatement = new sql.PreparedStatment(),
        sqlQuery = "select * from users where (username = @username and password = @password)"
    
    preparedStatement.input('username', sqlVarChar(50))
    preparedStatement.input('password', sqlVarChar(50))
    preparedStatement.prepare(sqlQuery)
    .then(function(){
        return preparedStatement.execute({username: username, password: password})
            .then(function(recordset){
                if(recordset.length == 1){
                    loggedIn = true
                    //successful log in
                } else {
                    //authentication failed
                }
            })
        })
    .catch(next)
}
```

Comment: yes, but it doesn't verify that username and password have sql inside, or does it?

Comment: even if it did say username was `;select * from users`. Prepared statement will prevent that from executing. It would be an odd user name but not sql injection.